# sizeToFit implementation in iOS

Tags: ios, cocoa-touch, uilabel

I'm a new developer to iOS. I'm currently developing an iOS app, and found some abnormalities in iOS. Please help me understand.

1. How does sizeToFit work? I have a UILabel which has dynamic length depending on the string. When I say setNumberOfLines:0 and [UILabel sizeToFit] then it adjusts everything nicely. However when I immediately send sizeToFit message to the view containing this label, it stops working. Am I approaching this in a wrong method? What I desire to have in my app is to adjust the height of the view depending on the height of the UILabel.

Feel free to more details.

Comment: possible duplicate of [sizeToFit is functioning oddly](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8556880/sizetofit-is-functioning-oddly) (not an exact duplicate, but solution is possibly similar)

Comment: You could always adjust the frame of the view manually rather than using `sizetofit` since you know the label's location and size now.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First get size of your label. Apply `sizeToFit` on your label and then set size of your view using label's old and new size.

```
CGSize labelOldHeight = self.label.bounds.size.height;    
[self.label sizeToFit];
self.view.frame = CGRectMake(self.view.frame.origin.x, self.view.frame.origin.y, self.view.bounds.size.width, self.view.bounds.size.height + self.label.bound.size.height - labelOldHeight);
```